# Why do these Auto Layout constraints for a UIView prevent UIButton subviews from receiving touch events?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm using auto layout, programmatically. I've got a simple `UIViewController` with a few controls, including two `UIButton`s arranged side-by-side. I often group related controls within a `UIView`, to act as a container, making the arrangement of *groups-of-controls* a bit easier to manage. You'll see that below with `_iapButtonsView`, which holds the two buttons and some spacers.

**My question**. In the following example, I was caught out by what I thought was a valid change to the constraints, that actually resulted in the `UIButton`s *not* receiving touch events.

Code extract - constraints in which the buttons **do** receive touch events:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    _buyButton = [ViewCreationHelper createRoundedBorderButtonBold];
    [_buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _restoreButton = [ViewCreationHelper createRoundedBorderButton];
    [_restoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(restorePurchaseTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _iapButtonsView = [UIView new];
    _iapButtonsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [contentView addSubview:_iapButtonsView];

    ...

    [_iapButtonsView addSubview:_buyButton];
    [_iapButtonsView addSubview:_restoreButton];

    // Constraints
    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, contentView, iapDesciption, _iapButtonsView, _buyButton, _restoreButton, spacer1, spacer2, spacer3);

    ...

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-25-[iapDesciption]-40-[_iapButtonsView]|"
                   options:0
                   metrics:nil
                   views:views];

    [contentView addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[_iapButtonsView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [contentView addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[spacer1][_buyButton(==120.0)][spacer2(==spacer1)][_restoreButton(==_buyButton)][spacer3(==spacer1)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:views];
    [_iapButtonsView addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_buyButton(==80.0)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [_iapButtonsView addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_restoreButton(==80.0)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [_iapButtonsView addConstraints:constraints];

    ...
}
```

The constraints in question are the vertical constraints for `_iapButtonsView`. During development (this is an In-App Purchase screen) I had some *debug* controls at the bottom, which is why I had the trailing `|` connecting to the superview's bottom edge, like this:

```
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-25-[iapDesciption]-40-[_iapButtonsView][someSpacer][someControls]|"
```

When I took those *debug* controls out, I changed those constraints to be:

```
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-25-[iapDesciption]-40-[_iapButtonsView]"
```

thinking that was more correct: *they're anchored from the top, only, the `_iapButtonsView` gets its size from its subviews (principally, the two buttons), so I shouldn't connect to the bottom edge of the superview*...

With that change, the buttons no longer receive touch events. To experiment, I tried explicitly setting the vertical size of `_iapButtonsView`, but still not connecting to the bottom edge of the superview, e.g.

```
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-25-[iapDesciption]-40-[_iapButtonsView(==80.0)]"
```

With those constraints, the buttons still do not receive touch events.

**What am I not understanding?**

*(Edit: I removed the duplicated `[contentView addSubview:_iapButtonsView];` in the code, above, per suggestion from **daddy warbucks**)*

Comment: I often have constraints which unexpectedly change the view's width or height to 0. Can you set  `_iapButtonsView.clipsToBounds = YES` to see if this reveals the problem? If so, your buttons should disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it, though I have tried giving _iapButtonsView a background colour... And it showed to be the expected size.

Comment: That would demonstrate the problem with the iabButtonsView too. Maybe it is the buttons themselves that are changing size.

Comment: @DanLoughney - I've tried `_iapButtonsView.clipsToBounds = YES`, but it doesn't reveal the problem. Along with the other experimentations, I think `_iapButtonsView` is being sized correctly... just not sure why the constraints lead to *no touch events coming through*... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One issue, you've called this two times:

```
[contentView addSubview:_iapButtonsView];
```

Not sure if this helps, but it could be an issue.

Also, you don't have to use "(==80.0)", just use "(80.0)", or even "(80)" not sure if this helps, but hey, it could, right?

Comment: Well spotted. I thought the double `[contentView addSubview:_iapButtonsView];` was just an error from me editing the code extracts that I put in the question, but I've actually called that twice in the full `viewDidLoad` method. Unfortunately, removing the duplicate call doesn't correct/answer the behaviour I'm seeing, nor does the slimmer `(==80)` suggestion. Thanks for the spot and the suggestions ;)

Comment: I'm also assuming that your spacers have the property     translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to "NO" as well right? And per chance, is the UIView that contains the buttons nested inside a UIScrollView? In addition, have you tried this by setting the option "options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY" to "options:0" instead? I only program using programmatic views and my code usually ends up being a thousand lines of code per view depending on complexity, and I've never used the "NSLayoutFormat ..." options, this is just a guess, but maybe worth a shot. I always set options to "options:0"

Comment: I'd also change this "[_iapButtonsView addConstraints:constraints];" to this: "[_iapButtonsView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[_iapButtonsView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];" and remove these lines: " [_iapButtonsView addConstraints:constraints];" you can just add these constraints without first setting them to a variable "constraints"

Comment: Ahh, also, I think this is going to do it, I now remember why this is happening, you have to add this "    [_buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];" ONLY AFTER you add your constraints, see if that helps

Comment: @Loxx YOU SAVED ME! Thank you for saving me a lot of time trying to mess with AutoLayout "ambiguity" or wrong bounds issues. I went down that path a bit but I decided to try your suggestion of adding the event _after_ the constraints had been created, and voila! everything now works.